# What is the proper php for an elasticsearch suggest query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to do a suggest term query from my elasticsearch server.

The following code is what I am attempting:

```
    //curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/_suggest?q= ...
function suggest($type, $q, $size=5) {

    $suggestion = array('my-suggestion' => array('text' => $q,'term' => array('size' => $size, 'field' => 'title')));
    return $this->call($type . '/_suggest?' . http_build_query(array('suggest' => $suggestion)));

}
```

Which returns a 404 error.  Here is an example of a URL it constructs:

```
http://localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/_suggest?suggest%5Bmy-suggestion%5D%5Btext%5D=test&suggest%5Bmy-suggestion%5D%5Bterm%5D%5Bsize%5D=5&suggest%5Bmy-suggestion%5D%5Bterm%5D%5Bfield%5D=title
```

The specifics of a suggest query are outlined here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html

The following from the same library does work correctly:

```
    //curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/_search?q= ...
function query($type, $q, $start=0, $limit=10, $sort=null) {
    if ($sort){
        $sort = json_encode($sort);
        return $this->call($type . '/_search?' . http_build_query(array('q' => $q, 'from' => $start, 'size' => $limit,"sort" => $sort)));
    }
    else
        return $this->call($type . '/_search?' . http_build_query(array('q' => $q, 'from' => $start, 'size' => $limit)));
}
```